# Treeview not adding properly as child

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, treeview

I have the code below to expand the tree node to add childeren to its parents , till the nth level.

Issue : The child is added to the first level always, instead it should have been added till the nth level, to its appropriate parent.

Code below:

```
public void Populate_Node(Object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{


        // Authenticating
        TreeProvider cmsTree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
        //selecting the expanding node
        var node = cmsTree.SelectSingleNode(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, "/Level1-2ndItem", "en-US");
        CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNodeCollection myChildren = node.AllChildren;

        //Making array of child treenodes  of selected node
        IEnumerable<CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode> TreeNodes = myChildren.AsEnumerable<CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode>();
        foreach (var tree in myChildren)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode ParenTreeNode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode();
            ParenTreeNode.Text = tree.NodeID.ToString() + ". " + SiteContext.CurrentSiteName;
            ParenTreeNode.Value = tree.NodeID.ToString();
            AddExpandedNodes(ParenTreeNode);

        }

}

private void AddExpandedNodes(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode TreeNode)
{  
    CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeProvider cmsTree = new CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeProvider(CMS.Membership.MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
    var node = cmsTree.SelectSingleNode(CMS.SiteProvider.SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, "/", "en-US");
    CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNodeCollection myChildren = node.AllChildren;
    IEnumerable<CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode> childTreeNodes = myChildren.AsEnumerable<CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode>().Where(x => x.NodeParentID == Convert.ToInt32(TreeNode.Value));
    foreach (var childTree in childTreeNodes)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode ChildNode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode();
        ChildNode.Text = childTree.NodeID.ToString() + ". " + childTree.DocumentName.ToString();
        ChildNode.Value = childTree.NodeID.ToString();      
        ChildNode.ChildNodes.Add(ChildNode);

        AddExpandedNodes(ChildNode);
        tvContentTree.Nodes.Add(ChildNode);
    }      
}
```

Comment: `AddNodesExpand` and `AddExpandedNodes` are same? If not can you share code of `AddNodesExpand`?

Comment: its same ...typo

Comment: I saw your other TreeView-related question also.  Instead of tree-noding yourself to death, you are better off manipulating the data source and rebinding your control.  Just my $0.02.

Comment: Ok i soved the above issue by adding and removing node by myself, Now issue is only expanding nodes, which is running on the below thread  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650795/treenode-not-expanding-after-removing-node?noredirect=1#comment76567211_44650795