# Treenode not expanding after removing node

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, treeview

I am trying to replace a tree node while expanding node (parent node). Replacing works fine. But the expansion not happening. Do you have any work around?

Code below:

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="tvContentTree" runat="server"  RootNodeStyle-CssClass="RootAllKeys"
            ParentNodeStyle-CssClass="ParentAllKeys" ShowCheckBoxes="All" ImageSet="Simple" NodeIndent="10"  OnTreeNodeExpanded="Populate_Node" >
                <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#DD5555" />
                <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="0px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
                <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#DD5555" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
            </asp:TreeView>


public void Populate_Node(Object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {    
        foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode tn in tvContentTree.Nodes)
        {
           tn.ChildNodes.RemoveAt(1);
           tn.ChildNodes.AddAt(1,ParentNode);                  
        }
    }
```

if i comment the line

> "tn.ChildNodes.RemoveAt(1);"

Then expansion works fine. So removeat function is causing the issue.

Comment: what is the value of variable nodeIndex?

Comment: its just a numeric value of index , just take it as 1 for example

Comment: i removed nodeindex variable from the question

Comment: I guess, AddAt should be something like ;tn.ChildNodes.AddAt(1,ParentNode);

Comment: yes corrected it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147155/discussion-between-smartestvega-and-ali).

Comment: So essentially, you want to remove a node, then add a node and have the node that was added be the selected node? is that accurate? Also what is driving your tree? Is it XML or a collection of objects or a data table or something else?

Comment: Yes i want to remove the expanded node(which only contain 2 levels),and add the nodes which contain children till the last level. Its not selected node its expanded node.

Answer (score 1):

You should find the node by its name & then remove it.

```
TreeNode tn = tvContentTree.FindNode("tn1");
tn.ChildNodes.RemoveAt(1);
```